# How to select required columns in csv file using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file with data looking like this.

```
Div,Date,HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG,FTR,HTHG,HTAG,HTR
I1,20/08/16,Juventus,Fiorentina,2,1,H,1,0,H
I1,20/08/16,Roma,Udinese,4,0,H,0,0,D
I1,21/08/16,Atalanta,Lazio,3,4,A,0,3,A
I1,21/08/16,Bologna,Crotone,1,0,H,0,0,D
```

I am trying to export first six columns like below to a new csv file.

```
Div,Date,HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG
I1,20/08/16,Juventus,Fiorentina,2,1
I1,20/08/16,Roma,Udinese,4,0
I1,21/08/16,Atalanta,Lazio,3,4
I1,21/08/16,Bologna,Crotone,1,0
```

I am using the following powershell command.

```
Import-Csv $infile -DeLimiter ","|
Select'Div','Date','HomeTeam','AwayTeam','FTHG','FTAG'| 
Export-Csv $trimfile -DeLimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
```

But my output csv file looks like this

```
"Div","Date","HomeTeam","AwayTeam","FTHG","FTAG"
"I1","20/08/16","Juventus","Fiorentina","2","1"
"I1","20/08/16","Roma","Udinese","4","0"
"I1","21/08/16","Atalanta","Lazio","3","4"
"I1","21/08/16","Bologna","Crotone","1","0"
```

The no.of columns are much higher in the actual file. Simplified it here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong? The quotes? 99% of csv-capable Readers understands and removes them..

Comment: yes. Then I have to import the data into sqlite, where the qoutes appear in all fields.

Comment: and if you have a "," into string? Quote are necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this code :

```
Import-Csv $infile -DeLimiter "," | 
Select-Object 'Div','Date','HomeTeam','AwayTeam','FTHG','FTAG' | 
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"', ""} | 
Out-File $trimfile
```